# Git change branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I created a new branch from master, I want to change to branch 'B' so I get the branch

```
git branch B 
git checkout B
git pull
```

but the old files still have old changes I want to delete all changes like I need to get a fresh branch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you want to reset all uncommitted changes, try:

```
git reset --hard
```

If this doesn't help, you might have started branch b based on the wrong commit.

Answer (score 0):

`git branch B` creates a new branch initially pointed to at the current branch, `master` in your case. If you want to create a new **empty** branch you need to create a branch not branched off any branch:

```
git checkout --orphan B
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnewbranchgt